# Score dependent of the position in an array

Tags: arrays, position, elasticsearch

I'm indexing documents in Elastic Search that contain arrays.

Sample documents :

```
doc1:
{
  ...
  actors: ["Tom Cruise", "Brad Pitt", ...],
  ...
}

doc2:
{
  ...
  actors: ["Brad Pitt", "Tom Cruise", ...],
  ...
}
```

When searching in such documents, I would like to have a score dependent of the matching position in the array, meaning that in the sample documents, searching "Tom Cruise" should boost the first document `doc1` because its matching position is `1`.

The only solution I can think of right now is by adding a limited number of fields (something like 5) containing the first actors, and putting boosts, like :

```
doc1:
{
  ...
  actors: ["Tom Cruise", "Brad Pitt", ...],
  actor1: "Tom Cruise",
  actor2: "Brad Pitt",
  ...
}
```

with `actor1` having a boost of `5`, `actor2` `4`, and so on.

Do you have a better solution to handle that, maybe using `custom_score` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/films

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/films/film/1 -d'{
    actors: ["Tom Cruise", "Brad Pitt", "Patrick Stewart", "Christopher Walken"]
}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/films/film/2 -d'{
    actors: ["Brad Pitt", "Patrick Stewart", "Tom Cruise", "Christopher Walken"]
}'
```

Then this query

```
{
    "query":{
        "custom_score":{
            "query": {"match_all":{}},
            "script":"length = _source.actors.size();
            found = false; index=0;
            while(!found && index<length){
              if(_source.actors[index] == target){
                found=true;
              }
              else{
                index+=1
              }
            }
            length - index;",
            "params":{
                "target": "Tom Cruise"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

calculates a score of 4 for the first film and 2 for the last one (if you're pasting this into curl, I had to remove all the line breaks in the custom script)

Some caveats:

- you probably want a better way of converting offset to score: this code returns the `length - offset` as the score so you can only really compare things of the same length
- it looks like `doc.actors` (i.e. the indexed data) only has an alphabetically sorted version of the array, which is obviously not useful, so I had to use `_source` which I believe is a lot slower. It might be acceptable performance-wise if the custom_score query wraps a filtered query.

Comment: performance wise it could be benefitial if you index it as actor_1, actor_2, ... (up to 5 or 10) and boost it accordingly ...